# After first jQuery ajax call jQuery style changes reset

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

There seems to be others having similar problems but still not finding an answer. Here is the scenario.

The user clicks a button which shows a hidden div containing a textarea where they can make a comment:

```
//show the div containing the textarea
$('#postTypeContainer').css({ 'display': 'block' });
```

Next the user enters a comment and clicks a button to submit and the div is hidden and some data is sent to the server:

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).show(); //shows a spinner
    }).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $(this).hide(); //hides the spinner

        //hide the div that was opened earlier
        $('#postTypeContainer').fadeOut('fast');
    });

    //send data
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: rootUri + "main.aspx/StartNewThread",
        data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (markUp) {
           //stuff
        }
    });
```

This all works as it should.

Now the user opens the div again via a click which works just fine

```
//show the div containing the textarea
$('#postTypeContainer').css({ 'display': 'block' });
```

Next the user types some data, in this case an @abc because they want to tag another user and the following occurs using jQuery on 'keyup':

```
//ajax call to find users matching the @abc
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: rootUri + "main.aspx/GetMatch",
        data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            //stuff

        }
    });
```

As soon as this ajax call returns the div that was opened is closed as if the DOM is being reset to what it was prior to the ajax call.  So in the middle of trying to interact with the textarea, the div closes on the user which is very frustrating. The only way to fix this is to refresh the page which is obviously what I want to avoid by using ajax. Hoping someone has an idea of what's wrong. The one thing I have tried unsuccessfully is when entering the function on keyup that makes the ajax call for tagging, I check the state of the div and then try to set it at the end of the ajax call to keep it open but that is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I dont quite understand your question, but use async:false property of ajax so the div fades out after ajax has finished

Comment: It might help if you post a jsfiddle link with the full code to demonstrate what exactly the problem is. But just an idea: `.ajaxComplete` is fired every time an ajax call completes, and in the call back for that you fade-out the `#postTypeContainer` div. So when your second ajax call completes it still hides it

Comment: @NicolásTorres that's why there is a callback function for the ajax call. 9 times out of 10 setting `async:false` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) is a global ajax event, fired every time a jQuery ajax event completes. So when your second ajax call completes it also hides the `postTypeContainer` div. I think you want to bind that hiding to the local complete event for that first ajax call.

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show(); //shows a spinner
}).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(this).hide(); //hides the spinner
});

//send data
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: rootUri + "main.aspx/StartNewThread",
    data: jsonText,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (markUp) {
       //stuff
    },
    complete: function() { // DO IT HERE

        //hide the div that was opened earlier
        $('#postTypeContainer').fadeOut('fast');

    }
});
```

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, that is it. I guess I need to read the jQuery documentation closer next time. Also I am seeing other symptoms of this being a global event. each time I have an ajax call I have that same code so the .ajaxComplete code is in several places which it should be. Only need it once for every ajax call if I am understanding correctly. Thanks for the help. learn something new everyday

Comment: @steven yep that's right. and as another point `.ajaxComplete` will be triggered as soon as the first ajax call completes, but if you want the loading spinner to show until the last ajax call has finished consider using `.ajaxStop` instead, that will wait for the last one. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/